# Ubuntu 15.10 wifi very unstable for Intel 3165

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I recently got a dell inspirion 7559. I heard it has hardware issues with this model. However, I succesfully installed 15.10 and installed the right graphic drivers and wireless drivers. It took me a while, but I am fairly sure I have the right drivers. The current problem I am having is unstable wifi connection. It connects to the wifi. But, when I go to the next room which isn't that far, It disconnects.

I also have windows on the computer, and I have no problems with wifi between rooms. Also, keep in mind, I am using this computer in a college campus. I usually connect to MSUNet 3.0.

here is output wirelessinfo

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15332599/

Edit:
This is wireless-info for second wifi spot where it doesn't work. I am just in the next room.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15332705/

Comment: I also have an HP Laptop with Intel 3165. Working fine with Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 with generic kernel 4.2. Yours kernel is certified by Intel also. Can you try some other wifi spot?

Comment: I added the wireless info from the second wifi spot which is right next door.  I have used both rooms using windows and it works like normal.

Comment: One thing I notice. The Frequency is usually around 5ghz which worries me a bit.